# how to fetch all the images from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, image

I have a database table where I have stored the images name along with the StudentId. I am fetching the images from a CURRENT student by it's studentId just like an Instagram home page where you can see all your uploaded images. I am not storing the images into a database but saving all the images into a directory called "upload/" and only the name of the images are getting saved into the db.

I have currently 3 images in my db with the same StudentId. But The problem is sometimes I am able to fetch only one image or none from it.
I have tried many code but it's still not working. I am not sure where is the mistake. Is it in looping or i am unable to fetch all the images from the db.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'common.php';
$id = $_SESSION['student'];
$command = "SELECT * FROM UsersImages WHERE StudentId = ".$id;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
$result = $stmt->execute();
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>hello</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="profile.php">Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <div>
     <?php
     $row = $stmt->fetch();
     $dir = $row['img_name'];
     foreach($dir as $images){
     echo "<img src=". $images." alt='images'>";
     }
     ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use $result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); instead of $row = $stmt->fetch(); $dir = $row['img_name']; . Once yhou are done with this try print_r($row); and let me now the out put you are getting. Thanks

Comment: I did what you said but got an error - Call to undefined method PDOStatement::get_result()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update your php code, you only store only image name which wrong process so it will not work and use **fetch_assoc()** to process your array data

```
<?php
     $row = $stmt->fetch();
     $dir = $row['img_name']; // this is wrong process
     foreach($dir as $images){
     echo "<img src=". $images." alt='images'>";
     }
     ?>
```

to

```
<?php
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // get all result using this
foreach ($results as $data)
{
    $images = $data['img_name']; // get image then use it in your code
    echo "<img src=". $images." alt='images'>";
}
?>
```

Try this

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // get all result using this
    $images = $results['img_name']; // get image then use it in your code
    echo "<img src=". $images." alt='images'>";
```

for more information about select data with loop

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: got an error : Call to undefined method PDOStatement::get_result() after executing your code.Thank you

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: i got a warning an I still can't see the image maybe because i am saving images name in data base not the image itself in the db. the warning is:Illegal string offset 'img_name'

Comment: yes then this is your db issue i think, can you see your table filed name?

Comment: just replace img_name to your table filed name, hope it will work

Comment: can you 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);

check result

Comment: you mean the name of the table itself?

Comment: no field name and it will multiple image for same student?

Comment: my field name was the sane one as above img_name?

Comment: can you print the result then show result , then it will easy to understand

Comment: yep i did and got :Array ( [img_name] => upload/34171665270_af5b954cf8_o.jpg [imageid] => 4 [StudentId] => 736760 ). it works but not when I put them in the while loop

Comment: please try last section my answer

Comment: if multiple image then first answer will work, first fetchAll then use foreach loop, hope it will also help you

Comment: Thank you so much it finally works just the way I needed. I really appreciate your help. Thank you for giving me your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the complete answer for this.

> - Add PDO::FETCH_ASSOC while fetching the data

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'common.php';
$id = $_SESSION['student'];
$command = "SELECT * FROM UsersImages WHERE StudentId = ".$id;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
$result = $stmt->execute();
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>hello</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="profile.php">Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <div>
     <?php
     $images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     foreach($images as $image){
     echo "<img src=". $image['img_name']." alt='images'>";
     }
     ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Hope this helps !**

Comment: I got a warning an I still can't see the image maybe because i am saving images name in data base not the image itself in the db. the warning is:Illegal string offset 'img_name'

Comment: can you `var_dump($images)` here? also updated the code, try adding `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`